# Can we have a way to easily mark B as a duplicate of A when A has been suggested as a duplicate of B?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

I just ran into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179493/adding-backslashes-without-escaping-python).  An old question was marked as a duplicate of a new question.  I cannot mark the new question as a duplicate of the old question because I get "This closure would result in the 'duplicate of' navigation only leading in a circle".  Seems we are temporarily stuck?  Is there a way we could fix this circle easily?

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with an older question being marked as a dupe of a newer. Why does the direction require reversing here?

Comment: You'd have to explicitly reopen the closed question, then vote to close in the other direction. But you need a compelling reason; just because the closed post is the older one is *not reason enough*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I can ask a question today which would make an older question a duplicate?  Really?

Comment: Yes, really. If a newer question has more information, better answers, covers *more* than just a narrow version of the issue, then it is **fine** to use a newer post as the dupe target.

Comment: @demongolem You *can*, that doesn't mean that you *should* or that your question would actually be the one left open if you asked a new one.  You should always leave the best Q/A pair open, and close whatever one is of lower value, regardless of age.

Comment: An older post does not necessarily have seniority *based on age alone*.

Comment: @demongolem, yes, it works that way sometimes, usually keeping the "better" question as the canonical.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info all, I just assumed always that the older question had precedence.,

Comment: Note that the post it was closed of as a dupe was **specifically created** to cover more information about this problem as there was no good canonical post on the problem.

Comment: Looking at the two questions and I would say that the answer on the second question is much better and provides more information.

Comment: @JoeW: You are welcome to join us in the [Python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) if you want to discuss the merits of that specific post and how it could be improved still.

Answer (score 11):

Please, do not reverse the duplication link here.

First of all, **older posts do not have priority based on age alone**. If a newer post covers a subject better, has more information and / or covers the subject in a more general scope, then it *does not matter* which post is the older one. We want to lead people to the best, highest quality information.

In this *specific case*, the newer post was created explicitly to cover the subject of Python backslash representation behaviour in a canonical post. The older post is *not* the better post here, and should remain closed as a duplicate.